# Java with Retrofit: the program doesn't terminate

Tags: retrofit2

I'm making some test with retrofit in Java. The following is the class that I'm using.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<List<User>> call = service.getJson();
        Response<List<User>> l = call.execute();
        System.out.println(l.body().get(0).getLogin());
    }

}
```

The API call work as expected and I receive the correct response. The problem is that the program doesn't terminate. I don't understand the reason of that behaviour.

What am i doing wrong?